# How to write JSON data into excel or csv format Android?

Tags: android, excel, csv, android-asynctask, apache-poi

I am trying to dump my `JSON` response into excel sheet with `.csv` file after getting response from server. I have tried with `poi-3.7.jar` and `poi-ooxml-3.11.jar` libraries. But I am getting an empty excel sheet.

Please check my below code for more reference.

My JSON URL `http://vehiclerescue.in/ideadarpan_beta/api/reportApp/get_tsm_data`

Code how I created rows:

```
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\File\\excel.xlsx"));

    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    //Create rows
    XSSFRow row0 = sheet.createRow(0);
    XSSFCell r1c0 = row0.createCell(0);
    r1c0.setCellValue("id\t");

    XSSFRow row1 = sheet.createRow(1);
    XSSFCell r1c1 = row1.createCell(0);
    r1c1.setCellValue("zone");


    XSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow(2);
    XSSFCell r1c2 = row2.createCell(0);
    r1c2.setCellValue("scd_code");

    XSSFRow row3 = sheet.createRow(3);
    XSSFCell r1c3 = row3.createCell(0);
    r1c3.setCellValue("asm_name");

    XSSFRow row4 = sheet.createRow(4);
    XSSFCell r1c4 = row4.createCell(0);
    r1c4.setCellValue("tsm_tse_name");

    XSSFRow row5 = sheet.createRow(5);
    XSSFCell r1c5 = row5.createCell(0);
    r1c5.setCellValue("tsm_tse_type");

    XSSFRow row6 = sheet.createRow(6);
    XSSFCell r1c6 = row6.createCell(0);
    r1c6.setCellValue("distributorname");

    XSSFRow row7 = sheet.createRow(7);
    XSSFCell r1c7 = row7.createCell(0);
    r1c7.setCellValue("dist_msisdn");

    XSSFRow row8 = sheet.createRow(8);
    XSSFCell r1c8 = row8.createCell(0);
    r1c8.setCellValue("se_msisdn");

    XSSFRow row9 = sheet.createRow(9);
    XSSFCell r1c9 = row9.createCell(0);
    r1c9.setCellValue("ret_msisdn");

    XSSFRow row10 = sheet.createRow(10);
    XSSFCell r1c10 = row10.createCell(0);
    r1c10.setCellValue("july_1st");

    XSSFRow row11 = sheet.createRow(11);
    XSSFCell r1c11 = row11.createCell(0);
    r1c11.setCellValue("july_2nd");

    XSSFRow row12 = sheet.createRow(12);
    XSSFCell r1c12 = row12.createCell(0);
    r1c12.setCellValue("july_3rd");

    XSSFRow row13 = sheet.createRow(13);
    XSSFCell r1c13 = row13.createCell(0);
    r1c13.setCellValue("july_4th");

    XSSFRow row14 = sheet.createRow(14);
    XSSFCell r1c14 = row14.createCell(0);
    r1c14.setCellValue("july_5th");


    XSSFRow row15 = sheet.createRow(15);
    XSSFCell r1c15 = row15.createCell(0);
    r1c15.setCellValue("july_6th");

    XSSFRow row16 = sheet.createRow(16);
    XSSFCell r1c16 = row16.createCell(0);
    r1c16.setCellValue("july_7th");

    XSSFRow row17 = sheet.createRow(17);
    XSSFCell r1c17 = row17.createCell(0);
    r1c17.setCellValue("july_8th");

    XSSFRow row18 = sheet.createRow(18);
    XSSFCell r1c18 = row18.createCell(0);
    r1c18.setCellValue("july_9th");

    XSSFRow row19 = sheet.createRow(19);
    XSSFCell r1c19 = row19.createCell(0);
    r1c19.setCellValue("july_10th");

    XSSFRow row20 = sheet.createRow(20);
    XSSFCell r1c20 = row20.createCell(0);
    r1c20.setCellValue("july_11th");

    XSSFRow row21 = sheet.createRow(21);
    XSSFCell r1c21 = row21.createCell(0);
    r1c21.setCellValue("july_12th");

    XSSFRow row22 = sheet.createRow(22);
    XSSFCell r1c22 = row22.createCell(0);
    r1c22.setCellValue("july_13th");

    XSSFRow row23 = sheet.createRow(23);
    XSSFCell r1c23 = row23.createCell(0);
    r1c23.setCellValue("july_14th");

    XSSFRow row24 = sheet.createRow(24);
    XSSFCell r1c24 = row24.createCell(0);
    r1c24.setCellValue("july_15th");

    XSSFRow row25 = sheet.createRow(25);
    XSSFCell r1c25 = row25.createCell(0);
    r1c25.setCellValue("july_16th");

    XSSFRow row26 = sheet.createRow(26);
    XSSFCell r1c26 = row26.createCell(0);
    r1c26.setCellValue("july_17th");

    XSSFRow row27 = sheet.createRow(27);
    XSSFCell r1c27 = row27.createCell(0);
    r1c27.setCellValue("july_18th");


    XSSFRow row28 = sheet.createRow(28);
    XSSFCell r1c28 = row28.createCell(0);
    r1c28.setCellValue("july_19th");

    XSSFRow row29 = sheet.createRow(29);
    XSSFCell r1c29 = row29.createCell(0);
    r1c29.setCellValue("july_20th");

    XSSFRow row30 = sheet.createRow(30);
    XSSFCell r1c30 = row30.createCell(0);
    r1c30.setCellValue("july_21st");

    XSSFRow row31 = sheet.createRow(31);
    XSSFCell r1c31 = row31.createCell(0);
    r1c31.setCellValue("july_22nd");

    XSSFRow row32 = sheet.createRow(32);
    XSSFCell r1c32 = row32.createCell(0);
    r1c32.setCellValue("july_23rd");

    XSSFRow row33 = sheet.createRow(33);
    XSSFCell r1c33 = row33.createCell(0);
    r1c33.setCellValue("july_24th");

    XSSFRow row34 = sheet.createRow(34);
    XSSFCell r1c34 = row34.createCell(0);
    r1c34.setCellValue("july_25th");

    XSSFRow row35 = sheet.createRow(35);
    XSSFCell r1c35 = row35.createCell(0);
    r1c35.setCellValue("july_26th");

    XSSFRow row36 = sheet.createRow(36);
    XSSFCell r1c36 = row36.createCell(0);
    r1c36.setCellValue("july_27th");

    XSSFRow row37 = sheet.createRow(37);
    XSSFCell r1c37 = row37.createCell(0);
    r1c37.setCellValue("july_23rd");

    XSSFRow row38 = sheet.createRow(38);
    XSSFCell r1c38 = row38.createCell(0);
    r1c38.setCellValue("july_28th");

    XSSFRow row39 = sheet.createRow(39);
    XSSFCell r1c39 = row39.createCell(0);
    r1c39.setCellValue("july_29th");

    XSSFRow row40 = sheet.createRow(40);
    XSSFCell r1c40 = row40.createCell(0);
    r1c40.setCellValue("july_30th");

    XSSFRow row41 = sheet.createRow(41);
    XSSFCell r1c41 = row41.createCell(0);
    r1c41.setCellValue("july_31st");

    XSSFRow row42 = sheet.createRow(42);
    XSSFCell r1c42 = row42.createCell(0);
    r1c42.setCellValue("grand_total");

    XSSFRow row43 = sheet.createRow(44);
    XSSFCell r1c43 = row43.createCell(0);
    r1c43.setCellValue("status");

    XSSFRow row44 = sheet.createRow(45);
    XSSFCell r1c44 = row44.createCell(0);
    r1c44.setCellValue("created_date");

    XSSFRow row45 = sheet.createRow(46);
    XSSFCell r1c45 = row45.createCell(0);
    r1c45.setCellValue("added_by");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Below is the code how I fetched data from that URL and created rows for that response.

```
private class converttocsv extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String cname = "'Goa'";

        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("auth_key", "auth123");
        data.put("role_type", "'4'");
        data.put("file_id", "4");

        String url = "http://vehiclerescue.in/ideadarpan_beta/api/reportApp/get_tsm_data";
        String result =  Json.performPostCall(url, data);
        Log.d("getornotss","getornot"+result);
        String projectname = null;
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            Log.e("TAG_jsonobj", ""+jsonArray);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                projectname = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                Log.e("projectname", projectname);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(projectname);
                Log.e("TAG_jsonobj", ""+jsonObject);

                XSSFRow row00 = sheet.getRow(0);
                XSSFCell r1c00 = row00.createCell(i+1);
                r1c00.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("id\t"));

                Log.e("row creating" +"****", "row created");

                XSSFRow row01 = sheet.getRow(1);
                XSSFCell r1c01 = row01.createCell(i+1);
                r1c01.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("zone"));

                XSSFRow row02 = sheet.getRow(2);
                XSSFCell r1c02 = row02.createCell(i+1);
                r1c02.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("scd_code"));

                XSSFRow row03 = sheet.getRow(3);
                XSSFCell r1c03 = row03.createCell(i+1);
                r1c03.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("asm_name"));

                XSSFRow row04 = sheet.getRow(4);
                XSSFCell r1c04 = row04.createCell(i+1);
                r1c04.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("tsm_tse_name"));

                XSSFRow row05 = sheet.getRow(5);
                XSSFCell r1c05 = row05.createCell(i+1);
                r1c05.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("tsm_tse_type"));

                XSSFRow row06 = sheet.getRow(6);
                XSSFCell r1c06 = row06.createCell(i+1);
                r1c06.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("distributorname"));

                XSSFRow row07 = sheet.getRow(7);
                XSSFCell r1c07 = row07.createCell(i+1);
                r1c07.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("dist_msisdn"));

                XSSFRow row08 = sheet.getRow(8);
                XSSFCell r1c08 = row08.createCell(i+1);
                r1c08.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("se_msisdn"));

                XSSFRow row09 = sheet.getRow(9);
                XSSFCell r1c09 = row09.createCell(i+1);
                r1c09.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("ret_msisdn"));

                XSSFRow row10 = sheet.getRow(10);
                XSSFCell r1c10 = row10.createCell(i+1);
                r1c10.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_1st"));

                XSSFRow row11 = sheet.getRow(11);
                XSSFCell r1c11 = row11.createCell(i+1);
                r1c11.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_2nd"));

                XSSFRow row12 = sheet.getRow(12);
                XSSFCell r1c12 = row12.createCell(i+1);
                r1c12.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_3rd"));

                XSSFRow row13 = sheet.getRow(13);
                XSSFCell r1c13 = row13.createCell(i+1);
                r1c13.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_4th"));

                XSSFRow row14 = sheet.getRow(14);
                XSSFCell r1c14 = row14.createCell(i+1);
                r1c14.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_5th"));

                XSSFRow row15 = sheet.getRow(15);
                XSSFCell r1c15 = row15.createCell(i+1);
                r1c15.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_6th"));

                XSSFRow row16 = sheet.getRow(16);
                XSSFCell r1c16 = row16.createCell(i+1);
                r1c16.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_7th"));

                XSSFRow row17 = sheet.getRow(17);
                XSSFCell r1c17 = row17.createCell(i+1);
                r1c17.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_8th"));

                XSSFRow row18 = sheet.getRow(18);
                XSSFCell r1c18 = row18.createCell(i+1);
                r1c18.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_9th"));

                XSSFRow row19 = sheet.getRow(19);
                XSSFCell r1c19 = row19.createCell(i+1);
                r1c19.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_10th"));

                XSSFRow row20 = sheet.getRow(20);
                XSSFCell r1c20 = row20.createCell(i+1);
                r1c20.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_11th"));

                XSSFRow row21 = sheet.getRow(21);
                XSSFCell r1c21 = row21.createCell(i+1);
                r1c21.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_12th"));

                XSSFRow row22 = sheet.getRow(22);
                XSSFCell r1c22 = row22.createCell(i+1);
                r1c22.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_13th"));

                XSSFRow row23 = sheet.getRow(23);
                XSSFCell r1c23 = row23.createCell(i+1);
                r1c23.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_14th"));

                XSSFRow row24 = sheet.getRow(24);
                XSSFCell r1c24 = row24.createCell(i+1);
                r1c24.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_15th"));

                XSSFRow row25 = sheet.getRow(25);
                XSSFCell r1c25 = row25.createCell(i+1);
                r1c25.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_16th"));

                XSSFRow row26 = sheet.getRow(26);
                XSSFCell r1c26 = row26.createCell(i+1);
                r1c26.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_17th"));

                XSSFRow row27 = sheet.getRow(27);
                XSSFCell r1c27 = row27.createCell(i+1);
                r1c27.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_18th"));

                XSSFRow row28 = sheet.getRow(28);
                XSSFCell r1c28 = row28.createCell(i+1);
                r1c28.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_19th"));

                XSSFRow row29 = sheet.getRow(29);
                XSSFCell r1c29 = row29.createCell(i+1);
                r1c29.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_20th"));

                XSSFRow row30 = sheet.getRow(30);
                XSSFCell r1c30 = row30.createCell(i+1);
                r1c30.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_21st"));

                XSSFRow row31 = sheet.getRow(31);
                XSSFCell r1c31 = row31.createCell(i+1);
                r1c31.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_22nd"));

                XSSFRow row32 = sheet.getRow(32);
                XSSFCell r1c32 = row32.createCell(i+1);
                r1c32.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_23rd"));

                XSSFRow row33 = sheet.getRow(33);
                XSSFCell r1c33 = row33.createCell(i+1);
                r1c33.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_24th"));

                XSSFRow row34 = sheet.getRow(34);
                XSSFCell r1c34 = row34.createCell(i+1);
                r1c34.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_25th"));

                XSSFRow row35 = sheet.getRow(35);
                XSSFCell r1c35 = row35.createCell(i+1);
                r1c35.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_26th"));

                XSSFRow row36 = sheet.getRow(36);
                XSSFCell r1c36 = row36.createCell(i+1);
                r1c36.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_27th"));

                XSSFRow row37 = sheet.getRow(37);
                XSSFCell r1c37 = row37.createCell(i+1);
                r1c37.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_28th"));

                XSSFRow row38 = sheet.getRow(38);
                XSSFCell r1c38 = row38.createCell(i+1);
                r1c38.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_29th"));

                XSSFRow row39 = sheet.getRow(39);
                XSSFCell r1c39 = row39.createCell(i+1);
                r1c39.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_30th"));

                XSSFRow row40 = sheet.getRow(40);
                XSSFCell r1c40 = row40.createCell(i+1);
                r1c40.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("july_31st"));

                XSSFRow row41 = sheet.getRow(41);
                XSSFCell r1c41 = row41.createCell(i+1);
                r1c41.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("grand_total"));

                XSSFRow row42 = sheet.getRow(42);
                XSSFCell r1c42 = row42.createCell(i+1);
                r1c42.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("status"));

                XSSFRow row43 = sheet.getRow(43);
                XSSFCell r1c43 = row43.createCell(i+1);
                r1c43.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("created_date"));

                XSSFRow row44 = sheet.getRow(44);
                XSSFCell r1c44 = row44.createCell(i+1);
                r1c44.setCellValue(jsonObject.getString("added_by"));
            }

            fis.close();
            fos =new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\File\\excel.xlsx"));
            workbook.write(fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        Log.e("TAG", s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really using Windows file path ("C:\\...") in a Android app?

Comment: As per [this Apache POI FAQ entry](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204) mixing POI jars between different versions is not supported! You need to use the jars from the same version

Comment: @MorrisonChang ya I am using windows file path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Download this two jar files **json-20140107.jar** and **commons-io-2.4.jar** put into your libs folder.

1.Download here:[commons-io-2.4.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4)

2.Download here:[json-20140107.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107)

```
try {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        try {
            String result = response.body().string();
            Log.d("files1st_reports", "***   " + result);

            JSONArray docs = new JSONArray(result);
            File file=new File(  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/gowthamguru"+"/tmp2/fromJSONss.csv");
            String csv = CDL.toString(docs);
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/vnd.ms-excel");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will Work Perfectly..

Comment: Thanks I will try and let you know @Mariyappan

Comment: Thanks buddy it saved my time

Comment: CDL keyword not found in android