# Convert FirebaseDatabase jsonObject to jsonArray and then that jsonArray to .xlsx format

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-json

I'm getting DataSnapshot from a Firebase database as a `JsonObject`. I have to convert this `JsonObjec`t into JsonArray and then that JsonArray into Excel format and then download that file into mobile storage. How can I do this?

Here I am getting the `DataSnapshot` on button click:

```java
 btnJson.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    long a = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    System.out.println("lc" + a);
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        System.out.println("response1" + ds);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Here is the response I am getting on button click in jsonObject:

> { key = 13uhnjvczw, value = {survey_title=Sports,
>   questions={4={type=2, title=Who is the top goal scorer in La Liga?},
>   0={options={0=13, 1=5}, type=1, title=How many ucl has real madrid
>   won},   1={options={0=Real Madrid fc, 1=Liverpool fc}, type=1,
>   title=Who is the current UCL champion?},   3={type=2, title=Who is the
>   top goal scorer in UCL?},  2={options={0=Cristiano Ronaldo, 1=Zinedine
>   Zidane}, type=1, title=Who is the all time top scorer of Real
>   Madrid?}}} }

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547767/how-to-write-json-data-into-excel-or-csv-format-android/45613338#45613338

Comment: @AnasMehar First I have to convert JsonObject to JsonArray how should I do that first?

Comment: You need to manual generate JosnArray from data snapshot for .xlsx

Comment: I have to do this all through App on a button click function

Comment: Are you using any POJO class for your objects in your database?

Comment: @AlexMamo no Iam not using any Pojo class

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Comment: {
  "Content" : {
    "Answers" : {
      "0582019101653" : {
        "06-August-201917:17:15" : {
          "Cheers 1" : [ "Jdj", "72728" ],
          "Cheers 2" : [ "Jdjjd", "83883", "Udxj", "Jxj" ],
          "Q1" : [ "Yes" ],
          "Q2" : [ "No\n" ],
          "Radi1" : [ "Ywu" ],
          "Radio2" : [ "6272" ]
        },
        "06-August-201917:22:40" : {
          "Cheers 1" : [ "Jdj" ],
          "Cheers 2" : [ "83883" ],
          "Q1" : [ "New" ],
          "Q2" : [ "" ],
          "Radi1" : [ "Jdje" ]
        }
      }
    },
  
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void saveCsv(JSONArray outerArray) throws IOException, JSONException {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            }
        }

        String fileName = referenceNo + " Result";
        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test/";
        File dir = new File(rootPath);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        File file = null;
        file = new File(rootPath, fileName);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        if (file.exists()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file), ',');
            for (int i = 0; i < outerArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray innerJsonArray = (JSONArray) outerArray.getJSONArray(i);


                    arrayOfArrays[k] = stringArray1;
                    writer.writeNext(arrayOfArrays[k]);
                    System.out.println("aa " + Arrays.toString(arrayOfArrays[k]));

                }
            }

            writer.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, fileName + " is been saved at " + rootPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.